# Multiple themes in fragment

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me why this isn't working? I want it to load a specific layout depending on what page is loaded. The if clause seems to be faulty. It's always going to the else.

```
     wordArray = getResources().getStringArray(resId);
     int resIdBack = getResources().getIdentifier(wordArray[5], "drawable", "com.bobgle.libretto");

    // If Background Image is dark use light theme, if not use dark theme.
    if(wordArray[5] == "libretto"){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_dark, container, false);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_light, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Also as a side note, I see that you have never accepted a answer on stackOverFlow, Please take your time to accept the answer that you think is correct by cross/tick it so you can help others with your question. Also it gives those who answers your question a reward for doing so.

Comment: @Rawa: I know! But more than often I get the answer from the comments to my question rather than the actual answers, so I can't accept them (or it would be wrong because they didn't help me).

Comment: Ok, good, thanks! Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing strings in Java you should use the `equals` method.

When using equal is good to remember that it can cause nullpointer if the object you are using equals on are null (duh!) so if you got a fixed string, that can't be null always use that first.

```
"libretto".equals(wordArray[5]) //Can't cause nullpointerexception.
wordArray[5].equals("libretto") //Can cause nullpointerexception if wordArray[5] is null.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) SO question explains why that is the case.